# Why use MVC/router

Tags: model-view-controller, url, router

I'm trying to comprehend the concept behind MVC and URL routing. I understand that it's good to seperate your code, hence MVC, but fail to understand the idea behind the URL router!

Instead of having a lot of rewrite rules in htaccess, I send all traffic to router.php, and in this page I have an array with page urls, and its corresponding PHP controller.

To keep it simple, I just include the controller, where the output finally is generated, however having seen lots of other practices, I'm afraid that im doing something wrong, or bad in some way..

Can someone please enlighten me, how to do a good, but simple URL router? Is it okay just to include the controller, which then generates the output? Perhaps someone has some information that describes the subject in details (something understandable for a beginner)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do URL routing.  Some are client side like with backbone.js, others are server side.  Doing it with .htaccess is one way, another is th way you are doing it by having a prerequisite path that is is either a hard path, or a regular expression that you parse and figure out where to send it.  None of them are 100% right or 100% wrong, it's all preference, and it sounds like you are doing just fine with a route file.

For more information on how different frameworks do routing you should read over the docs on routing for CodeIgniter, and Symfony frameworks to see 2 different styles of server side routing, and then maybe look at the backbone.js framework for client side routing just to see the similarities and differences.

Answer (score 2):

The router in the MVC concept decides which controller it has to load when a user requests a page. E.g. a user requests example.com/something/very/important, the router would now look for an action which is mapped to this route and execute it. There are different methods how you can accomplish that (simple include, instantiating a class and running a method etc.) but the most simple and still powerful solution I came up with is creating a separate class for every action. I've written a little article on that matter, since I've been asked this question several times, you can have a look at it here: [Writing a simple and fast mvc router with PHP](http://avendiart.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/writing-a-simple-and-fast-mvc-router-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET Routing module is responsible for mapping incoming browser requests to particular MVC controller actions.

Routing is a pattern matching system that monitor the incoming request and figure out what to do with that request. At runtime, Routing engine use the Route table for matching the incoming request's URL pattern against the URL patterns defined in the Route table. You can register one or more URL patterns to the Route table at Application_Start event.